# Use mongoose plugin in NESTjs

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

I am trying to use mongoose-paginate-v2, in the Nestjs project. My schema is like this:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type CarDocument = Car & Document;

import * as mongoosePaginate from 'mongoose-paginate-v2';

@Schema()
export class Car {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  id: number;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  brand: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  model: number;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  color: string;
}

export const CarSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Car);

CarSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
```

And my service like this:

```
import { Injectable, HttpException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Car, CarDocument } from './schemas/car.schema';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';

import { Cars } from './cars.mock';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

export interface ICarInterface {
  id: number;
  brand: string;
  color: string;
  model: number;
}

@Injectable()
export class CarService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(Car.name) private carModel: Model<CarDocument>) {}
  private cars = Cars;
  public getCars(): Promise<any> {
    return this.carModel.paginate.
  }
}
```

here i am unable use `this.carModel.paginate`, getting error `Property 'paginate' does not exist on type 'Model<CarDocument, {}, {}, {}>'`

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin adds methods to the model type, but since you're still using `Model` as the type, TypeScript doesn't know about it. In the [types for mongoose-paginate-v2](https://github.com/aravindnc/mongoose-paginate-v2/blob/master/index.d.ts), it opens up the `mongoose` module and adds a new interface `PaginateModel`. For models where you've wired up the plugin, you'll use that instead of just `Model`.

```js
import { PaginateModel } from 'mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class CarService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(Car.name) private carModel: PaginateModel<CarDocument>) {}
```